# How to define a function that takes all collections in C++

Tags: c++, templates, stl, c++17

I'm doing a little research for a course on which computing speed over collections on different cpu types. I'm writing my tests in C++ (bad choice as I started with the language three weeks ago) and I'm trying to measure the amount of clock ticks.

I thought I'd implement an arbitrary map (yes, yes, transform) function first. For some reason I decided to encapsulate the functions I'm writing in different classes. I first tried making a function that takes an arbitrary collection, but that didn't work, so I thought of making a function that takes two iterator pointers, so I'm currently having problems with this:

.h

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

class MapTests {
public:
    static unsigned long halve(unsigned long in);

    template <class InputIter>
    static clock_t getHalveTest(InputIter begin, InputIter end);
};
```

.cpp

```cpp
#include "MapTests.h"

unsigned long MapTests::halve(unsigned long in){ return in/2; }

template<class InputIter>
clock_t MapTests::getHalveTest(InputIter begin, InputIter end) {
    vector<unsigned long> store = {};
    auto beginTime = clock();
    transform(begin, end, store, &MapTests::halve);
    return clock()-beginTime;
}
```

I'm still planning on making a seperate function for std::map, but this is what I was planning to use for list, vector, array and such.

When I try to compile and print the clock ticks for the forward_list I get this monster of an error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "unsigned long MapTests::getHalveTest*> >(std::__1::__forward_list_iterator*>, std::__1::__forward_list_iterator*>)", referenced from:
>         _main in main.cpp.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

And I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here. I suspect I should do something with my template, but I don't know what.

Comment: Your code is doing the moral equivalent of MapTests.h `#define GET_HALVE_TEST /*macro body in MapTests.cpp*/` and main.cpp that uses the macro doesn't see anything.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what you mean by this, can you elaborate please?

Comment: Then my analogy was poor.  A template is instantiated on demand.  Your `main.cpp` tries to instantiate the template, but cannot, because its implementation was in a different file.

Comment: Oh wow I see what you're saying. I got it working now. Thanks a lot!